# WIX Cannot access the server root directory for the installation to proceed

Tags: installation, wix, registry, 32bit-64bit, bootstrapper

I'm trying to **install** a **bootstrapper** which should, depending on the program platform, install either a `32bit` or `64bit` driver.

This is the error I'm getting when I try **install**:

[image]

I have two **RegistrySearch's** to check if the program is installed and what the bitness of the program is. In the log file, it is telling me that the `64bit` MsiPackage install condition evaluates to **true** and the `32bit` evaluates to **false**.

The same error happens when I try install the `32bit` `<MsiPackage>` separately as my PC and program is `x64`, I expect it to give me that error.

That must mean it is still trying to install the `32bit` despite the `InstallConditions`.

**Msi Packages:**

```
<MsiPackage Id="YourProgram_x64" SourceFile="E:\Products\[MY_PROGRAM]\ISSUE_DISKS_x64\Drivers\[MY_DRIVER]\Setup.msi"
        InstallCondition="(ProgramInstalled = 1) AND (ProgramBitness = 64) AND (VersionNT64)" />
<MsiPackage Id="YourProgram_x86" SourceFile="E:\Products\[MY_PROGRAM]\ISSUE_DISKS\Drivers\[MY_DRIVER]\Setup.msi"
        InstallCondition="(ProgramInstalled = 1) AND (ProgramBitness = 32) AND (NOT VersionNT64)" />
```

Below is a snippet of the **log file** created when I run the `.msi` :

```
           ******* Product: E:\Products\[PRODUCT_NAME]\ISSUE_DISKS_x64\Drivers\[DRIVER_NAME]\setup.msi
           ******* Action: INSTALL
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:115]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:197]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:199]: Machine policy value 'LimitSystemRestoreCheckpointing' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:199]: Note: 1: 1715 2: [DRIVER_NAME] 
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:199]: Calling SRSetRestorePoint API. dwRestorePtType: 0, dwEventType: 102, llSequenceNumber: 0, szDescription: "Installed [DRIVER_NAME]".
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:221]: The System Restore service is disabled. Returned status: 1058. GetLastError() returned: 1058
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:226]: File will have security applied from OpCode.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:298]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'E:\Products\[PRODUCT_NAME]\ISSUE_DISKS_x64\Drivers\[DRIVER_NAME]\setup.msi' against software restriction policy
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:300]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: E:\Products\[PRODUCT_NAME]\ISSUE_DISKS_x64\Drivers\[DRIVER_NAME]\setup.msi has a digital signature
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:502]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: E:\Products\[PRODUCT_NAME]\ISSUE_DISKS_x64\Drivers\[DRIVER_NAME]\setup.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:502]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:535]: End dialog not enabled
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:535]: Original package ==> E:\Products\[PRODUCT_NAME]\ISSUE_DISKS_x64\Drivers\[DRIVER_NAME]\setup.msi
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:535]: Package we're running from ==> C:\WINDOWS\Installer\536c0e6.msi
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:538]: APPCOMPAT: Compatibility mode property overrides found.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:539]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{[MY_CODE]}'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:539]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:565]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:565]: User policy value 'TransformsAtSource' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:565]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:565]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:565]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:565]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:567]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{[MY_CODE]}'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:567]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:567]: Transforms are not secure.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:567]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiLogFileLocation property. Its value is 'c:\temp\imp.log'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:567]: Command Line: SERVERINSTALLED=C:\[PROGRAM_NAME] LOCKTYPESW=0 BIN=C:\[PROGRAM_NAME]\BIN\ TARGETDIR=D:\ ANALOGPREFIX=AG ANALOGCHANNELS=80 DIGITALPREFIX=0 DIGITALCHANNELS=0 ANALOGOPREFIX=0 ANALOGOCHANNELS=0 DIGITALOPREFIX=0 DIGITALOCHANNELS=0 MAXDRIVERS=1 INSTALLLOCATION=C:\[PROGRAM_NAME]\ CURRENT_CONFIG=C:\[PROGRAM_NAME]\CURRENT_CONFIG\ CURRENTDIRECTORY=E:\Products\[PRODUCT_NAME]\ISSUE_DISKS_x64\Drivers\[DRIVER_NAME] CLIENTUILEVEL=0 CLIENTPROCESSID=18696 ACTION=INSTALL USERNAME=HP COMPANYNAME=HP SOURCEDIR=E:\Products\[PRODUCT_NAME]\ISSUE_DISKS_x64\Drivers\[DRIVER_NAME]\ EXECUTEACTION=INSTALL VERSIONINFO=6.8.9.0 PRODUCTNAME=[PROGRAM_NAME] INSTALLDIR=C:\[PROGRAM_NAME] KEYVALIDATED=1 DEVICEEXISTS=3 ROOTDRIVE=D:\ INSTALLLEVEL=1 WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID=1 LOCKTYPE=0 SECONDSEQUENCE=1 ADDLOCAL=MainApp,VCRedistVS12x64,VCRedistVS15x64 ACTION=INSTALL 
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:567]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackageCode property. Its value is '{[MY_CODE]}'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:567]: Product Code passed to Engine.Initialize:           ''
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:567]: Product Code from property table before transforms: '{[MY_CODE]}'
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:567]: Product Code from property table after transforms:  '{[MY_CODE]}'
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:567]: Product not registered: beginning first-time install
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:567]: Product {[MY_CODE]} is not managed.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:568]: MSI_LUA: Credential prompt not required, user is an admin
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:568]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ProductState property. Its value is '-1'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:568]: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:569]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:569]: Adding new sources is allowed.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:569]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackagecodeChanging property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:569]: Package name extracted from package path: 'setup.msi'
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:569]: Package to be registered: 'Setup.msi'
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: Product installation will be elevated because user is admin and product is being installed per-machine.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: Running product '{[MY_CODE]}' with elevated privileges: Product is assigned.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SERVERINSTALLED property. Its value is 'C:\[PROGRAM_NAME]'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding LOCKTYPESW property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding BIN property. Its value is 'C:\[PROGRAM_NAME]\BIN\'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding TARGETDIR property. Its value is 'D:\'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ANALOGPREFIX property. Its value is 'AG'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ANALOGCHANNELS property. Its value is '80'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DIGITALPREFIX property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DIGITALCHANNELS property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ANALOGOPREFIX property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ANALOGOCHANNELS property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DIGITALOPREFIX property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DIGITALOCHANNELS property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MAXDRIVERS property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding INSTALLLOCATION property. Its value is 'C:\[PROGRAM_NAME]\'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CURRENT_CONFIG property. Its value is 'C:\[PROGRAM_NAME]\CURRENT_CONFIG\'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CURRENTDIRECTORY property. Its value is 'E:\Products\[PRODUCT_NAME]\ISSUE_DISKS_x64\Drivers\[DRIVER_NAME]'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTUILEVEL property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTPROCESSID property. Its value is '18696'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding USERNAME property. Its value is 'HP'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding COMPANYNAME property. Its value is 'HP'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SOURCEDIR property. Its value is 'E:\Products\[PRODUCT_NAME]\ISSUE_DISKS_x64\Drivers\[DRIVER_NAME]\'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding EXECUTEACTION property. Its value is 'INSTALL'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VERSIONINFO property. Its value is '6.8.9.0'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PRODUCTNAME property. Its value is '[PROGRAM_NAME]'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding INSTALLDIR property. Its value is 'C:\[PROGRAM_NAME]'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding KEYVALIDATED property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DEVICEEXISTS property. Its value is '3'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ROOTDRIVE property. Its value is 'D:\'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding INSTALLLEVEL property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding LOCKTYPE property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:571]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ADDLOCAL property. Its value is 'MainApp,VCRedistVS12x64,VCRedistVS15x64'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:572]: Machine policy value 'DisableAutomaticApplicationShutdown' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:580]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiRestartManagerSessionKey property. Its value is '[MY_KEY]'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:580]: RESTART MANAGER: Session opened.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:580]: Engine has iefSecondSequence set to true.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:580]: TRANSFORMS property is now: 
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:580]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting SOURCEDIR property. Its current value is 'E:\Products\[PRODUCT_NAME]\ISSUE_DISKS_x64\Drivers\[DRIVER_NAME]\'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:580]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionDatabase property. Its value is '405'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:588]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:591]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\Favorites
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:594]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:597]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\Documents
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:600]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:602]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:605]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:608]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:608]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:610]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Local
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:612]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\Pictures
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:617]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:620]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:622]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:625]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:628]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Public\Desktop
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:633]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:636]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:638]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:640]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:642]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\Desktop
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:645]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:646]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\Fonts
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:647]: Note: 1: 2898 2: MS Sans Serif 3: MS Sans Serif 4: 0 5: 16 
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:675]: MSI_LUA: Setting MsiRunningElevated property to 1 because the install is already running elevated.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:675]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiRunningElevated property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:675]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Privileged property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:676]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATABASE property. Its value is 'C:\WINDOWS\Installer\536c0e6.msi'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:676]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OriginalDatabase property. Its value is 'E:\Products\[PRODUCT_NAME]\ISSUE_DISKS_x64\Drivers\[DRIVER_NAME]\setup.msi'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:676]: Machine policy value 'MsiDisableEmbeddedUI' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:676]: EEUI - Disabling MsiEmbeddedUI for service because it's not a quiet/basic install
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:676]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PatchPackage 
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:676]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:676]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:676]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UILevel property. Its value is '5'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:677]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Preselected property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:678]: APPCOMPAT: [DetectVersionLaunchCondition] Launch condition already passes.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:681]: Doing action: INSTALL
Action 09:21:09: INSTALL. 
Action start 09:21:09: INSTALL.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:684]: Running ExecuteSequence
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:684]: Doing action: System64Folder_amd64_VC.7631C5EE_5656_3421_AE44_00C5FBD84302
Action 09:21:09: System64Folder_amd64_VC.7631C5EE_5656_3421_AE44_00C5FBD84302. 
Action start 09:21:09: System64Folder_amd64_VC.7631C5EE_5656_3421_AE44_00C5FBD84302.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:687]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding System64Folder_amd64_VC.7631C5EE_5656_3421_AE44_00C5FBD84302 property. Its value is 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\'.
Action ended 09:21:09: System64Folder_amd64_VC.7631C5EE_5656_3421_AE44_00C5FBD84302. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:688]: Doing action: System64Folder.7631C5EE_5656_3421_AE44_00C5FBD84302
Action 09:21:09: System64Folder.7631C5EE_5656_3421_AE44_00C5FBD84302. 
Action start 09:21:09: System64Folder.7631C5EE_5656_3421_AE44_00C5FBD84302.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:690]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding System64Folder.7631C5EE_5656_3421_AE44_00C5FBD84302 property. Its value is 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\'.
Action ended 09:21:09: System64Folder.7631C5EE_5656_3421_AE44_00C5FBD84302. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:691]: Doing action: System64Folder_amd64_VC.AF4EABEE_4589_3789_BA0A_C83A71662E1D
Action 09:21:09: System64Folder_amd64_VC.AF4EABEE_4589_3789_BA0A_C83A71662E1D. 
Action start 09:21:09: System64Folder_amd64_VC.AF4EABEE_4589_3789_BA0A_C83A71662E1D.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:693]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding System64Folder_amd64_VC.AF4EABEE_4589_3789_BA0A_C83A71662E1D property. Its value is 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\'.
Action ended 09:21:09: System64Folder_amd64_VC.AF4EABEE_4589_3789_BA0A_C83A71662E1D. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:694]: Doing action: System64Folder.AF4EABEE_4589_3789_BA0A_C83A71662E1D
Action 09:21:09: System64Folder.AF4EABEE_4589_3789_BA0A_C83A71662E1D. 
Action start 09:21:09: System64Folder.AF4EABEE_4589_3789_BA0A_C83A71662E1D.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:696]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding System64Folder.AF4EABEE_4589_3789_BA0A_C83A71662E1D property. Its value is 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\'.
Action ended 09:21:09: System64Folder.AF4EABEE_4589_3789_BA0A_C83A71662E1D. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:697]: Doing action: System64Folder_amd64_VC.8EA4B0FB_370C_3FD3_9CFD_27264D9615E4
Action 09:21:09: System64Folder_amd64_VC.8EA4B0FB_370C_3FD3_9CFD_27264D9615E4. 
Action start 09:21:09: System64Folder_amd64_VC.8EA4B0FB_370C_3FD3_9CFD_27264D9615E4.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:700]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding System64Folder_amd64_VC.8EA4B0FB_370C_3FD3_9CFD_27264D9615E4 property. Its value is 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\'.
Action ended 09:21:09: System64Folder_amd64_VC.8EA4B0FB_370C_3FD3_9CFD_27264D9615E4. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:701]: Doing action: WindowsFolder_amd64_VC.8EA4B0FB_370C_3FD3_9CFD_27264D9615E4
Action 09:21:09: WindowsFolder_amd64_VC.8EA4B0FB_370C_3FD3_9CFD_27264D9615E4. 
Action start 09:21:09: WindowsFolder_amd64_VC.8EA4B0FB_370C_3FD3_9CFD_27264D9615E4.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:704]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WindowsFolder_amd64_VC.8EA4B0FB_370C_3FD3_9CFD_27264D9615E4 property. Its value is 'C:\WINDOWS\'.
Action ended 09:21:09: WindowsFolder_amd64_VC.8EA4B0FB_370C_3FD3_9CFD_27264D9615E4. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:705]: Doing action: WindowsFolder_amd64_VC.C7F737EB_3325_3BEE_8D0D_DEF2DE62486A
Action 09:21:09: WindowsFolder_amd64_VC.C7F737EB_3325_3BEE_8D0D_DEF2DE62486A. 
Action start 09:21:09: WindowsFolder_amd64_VC.C7F737EB_3325_3BEE_8D0D_DEF2DE62486A.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:709]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding WindowsFolder_amd64_VC.C7F737EB_3325_3BEE_8D0D_DEF2DE62486A property. Its value is 'C:\WINDOWS\'.
Action ended 09:21:09: WindowsFolder_amd64_VC.C7F737EB_3325_3BEE_8D0D_DEF2DE62486A. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:709]: Doing action: System64Folder_amd64_VC.C7F737EB_3325_3BEE_8D0D_DEF2DE62486A
Action 09:21:09: System64Folder_amd64_VC.C7F737EB_3325_3BEE_8D0D_DEF2DE62486A. 
Action start 09:21:09: System64Folder_amd64_VC.C7F737EB_3325_3BEE_8D0D_DEF2DE62486A.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:711]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding System64Folder_amd64_VC.C7F737EB_3325_3BEE_8D0D_DEF2DE62486A property. Its value is 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\'.
Action ended 09:21:09: System64Folder_amd64_VC.C7F737EB_3325_3BEE_8D0D_DEF2DE62486A. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:712]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
Action 09:21:09: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 09:21:09: FindRelatedProducts.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:715]: Skipping FindRelatedProducts action: already done on client side
Action ended 09:21:09: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 0.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:716]: Doing action: SetFirstInstall
Action 09:21:09: SetFirstInstall. 
Action start 09:21:09: SetFirstInstall.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:719]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding FirstInstall property. Its value is 'true'.
Action ended 09:21:09: SetFirstInstall. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:720]: Skipping action: SetUpgrading (condition is false)
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:720]: Skipping action: SetUninstalling (condition is false)
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:720]: Skipping action: SetMaintenance (condition is false)
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:720]: Skipping action: SetPRODUCTTYPE (condition is false)
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:720]: Doing action: AppSearch
Action 09:21:09: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
Action start 09:21:09: AppSearch.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:723]: Skipping AppSearch action: already done on client side
Action ended 09:21:09: AppSearch. Return value 0.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:724]: Doing action: LaunchConditions
Action 09:21:09: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
Action start 09:21:09: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 09:21:09: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (CC:50) [09:21:09:727]: Doing action: GetOrchDir
Action 09:21:09: GetOrchDir. 
Action start 09:21:09: GetOrchDir.
MSI (s) (CC:4C) [09:21:09:741]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSIC2DA.tmp, Entrypoint: GetOrchDir
MSI (s) (CC:64) [09:21:09:743]: Generating random cookie.
MSI (s) (CC:64) [09:21:09:754]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 4260 (0x10A4).
```

Comment: You'd need to look into the log files to get more context on the failure. Not enough context to start guessing.

Comment: @Rob Mensching In the log file, I've found these errors: **1.** 'Could not create system restore point, error 0x80070422' , **2.** 'Error 0x80070643 Failed to install MSI package' , **3.** 'Error 0x80070643 Failed to execute MSI package' , **4.** 'Error 0x80070643 Failed to configure per-machine MSI package' .

Comment: The program is x64 and so is the driver, I've tested it by installing the Setup.msi for the x64 version and it installed correctly. In the log file has 'Condition VersionNT64 evaluates to true' so it is trying to install the correct setup. Hard to tell where it's going wrong.

Comment: Those are messages in the Bundle log file telling you that the MSI package failed. The log file for that MSI should have more information.

Comment: @Rob Mensching I've included more info in my question. I got more insight into the problem from the log file associated with the `.EXE` installation using this line **Bootstrapper.exe -l "c:\temp\LogFileName.log"**. I'd appreciate the help thx :)

Comment: That is the Bundle log file telling you that the MSI package failed. The log file for that MSI should have more information.

Comment: @Rob Mensching I have added a snippet of the log file in my question. If you need more info let me know. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I got some help and found the solution to this problem. Hopefully it works for you. If I add this line into the `<MsiPackage>` the bootstrapper will work as expected and successfully install the correct `Setup.msi` :

```
DisplayInternalUI="yes"
```

So for example your **Msi Packages** may look like this:

```
<MsiPackage Id="Setup"
            Compressed="yes"
            DisplayName="My Driver x32" 
            DisplayInternalUI="yes"
            SourceFile="E:\Products\[PRODUCT_NAME]\ISSUE_DISKS\Drivers\[DRIVER_NAME]\Setup.msi"
            InstallCondition="(ProgramInstalled32 = 1)" />
        
<MsiPackage Id="Setup_x64" 
            Compressed="yes"
            DisplayName="My Driver x64"
            DisplayInternalUI="yes"
            SourceFile="E:\Products\[PRODUCT_NAME]\ISSUE_DISKS_x64\Drivers\[DRIVER_NAME]\Setup.msi"
            InstallCondition="(ProgramInstalled64 = 1)"/>
```